# Eclipse + CMake: Eclipse index unable to resolve header files

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2024-03. I have set it up to build a C++ project with CMake. The build directory and source tree are at the same level. The build works OK. Navigation, code assists, etc are all OK.

The only issue is that the indexer is not able to resolve include files outside the source tree. For example C++/Boost headers. Here is a screenshot. As can be seen, they are present in the build includes and the build passes successfully. Any idea how to resolve this?

Since there is CMake driven, I don't see an option to add C++ preprocess/header paths like you normally see in the Project -> Properties.

[image]